# session and cookie to handle data

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am making an application where I need to save affiliation data

One of my friend suggested me that I can do it with sessions and cookies, but I don't have proper guidance on how can I achieve it.

Here is what I know.

There would be affiliation code for each product
When a visitor clicks on affiliation code, I would create a session at server side
I would save session id on client side using cookie, so that affiliation can be recorded for future visit.

**There are two questions**

1. How can I save session-id with-in cookie? How can I get session-id?
2. I think session gets destroyed as soon as user/visitor closes browser, am I right? How can I save sessions for longer period of time, say till time I set my cookie expiration?

Comment: I'm afraid the suggestion is wrong, sessions are not an instrument to store data for a long time.

Comment: Correct, they are not good for long term storage. However, they can be used to link a visitor to a database record, which the OP is trying to do. It's simple visitor tracking...

Comment: I meant "long time" not "long term" . His description sounds like he wants to hold the data for maybe days or weeks, no use case for sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your cookie expiration to some time far in the future, then track client side whenever the user visits your site.  This approach will break if they clear their cookies.

Another option is to match the user agent string and IP address.  This isn't 100% accurate, but will get you close.

The best option, imho, is to require a sign-up for the users.  This way, you can confirm their identity and continue to track them whenever they login.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can get the current session ID by calling

```
$_currentSessionId = session_id()
```

To write it to a cookie, just do the following:

```
$_expires = 0;
setcookie( 'YOUR_SID', $_currentSessionId, $_expires );
```

Upon return, pull the SID from the cookie:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['YOUR_SID'] ) ) {
    $_currentSessionId = $_SESSION['YOUR_SID'];
    // Do your thing...
}
```

If you pass $_expires of 0 to setcookie, it will be a session-based cookie, or will be destroyed when the user closes the browser. If you set $_expires to something large, it will expire later (it should be the number of seconds from now).

I've seen people use:

```
$_expires = pow(2,31)-1;
```

for a very long-lasting cookie.